# ffmpeg equivalent for sox -t ima

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, sox, adpcm

I am trying to use ffmpeg to combine 1 audio file (ADPCM) and 1 video file (h264) into single mp4. Video by file conversion works fine but ffmpeg chokes on guessing audio input. I can't figure out how to tell ffmpeg which params to use to decode raw audio file.

Currently I first run sox to convert raw audio to wav:

```
sox -t ima -r 8000 audio.raw audio.wav
```

... then feed audio.wav from sox as ffmpeg input

```
ffmpeg -i video.raw -i audio.wav movie.mp4
```

I am trying to avoid sox step and use audio.raw in ffmpeg.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have headless audio, you should tell ffmpeg about the sample format and (optionally) sample rate, audio channels, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i video.raw -f s16le -ar 22050 -ac 1 -i audio.raw movie.mp4
```

To check supported PCM formats you may use this command:

```
ffmpeg -formats 2>&1 | grep -i pcm
```